How to get xpath of an item that disappears
I am trying to get the xpath of particular date from from calendar. When I click the date & inspect the calendar disappears and the element also disappears from DOM. Tried with freezing the screen as well.
When I open calendar & press f8 to freeze screen the calendar disappears & screen doesn't freeze.
I am beginner in selenium. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

How about using dev console inspect?

if this is a browser control you won't be able to access it beyond   The options are not a part of the DOM.  You should be able to send keys to it though.

What's the URL?

As LMC suggested, try the following...

Use Chrome DevTools to open the page's rendered HTML (open page in Chrome > right click on page > Inspect > select the Elements tab)
Copy the full rendered HTML (right click the  tag > Copy > Copy element) and paste it into a text editor
Construct the XPath based on the element location (this might be helpful: https://devhints.io/xpath)

